# How to include custom PHP file both in header and footer files

Tags: php, customization, include

I have created a custom file that both the header and the footer needs to render certain content.

If I only do `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/myTheme/myCustomFile.php');` in the `header.php` file it works as expected BUT only in the header.

Likewise with the footer, If I only do `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/myTheme/myCustomFile.php');` in the `footer.php` file it works as expected BUT only in the footer.

The moment I have the include on both files, the page renders up until the footer starts and then stops rendering.

How can I include this file so it can be accessed from anywhere in the theme?

I also tried the other import methods in PHP - require, require_once, and include_once – same deal.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `myCustomFile.php` is in theme directory, so just add `include 'myCustomFile.php';` in both files (footer and header). Do you have function or class definitions in included file?

Comment: @nmr thanks, but still not working. Same thing is happening, the page renders fine up until the footer and then stops rendering. But the header renders the information from `myCustomFile.php` fine. I do have functions in the custom file, but I don't think they are interfering because then it would not render on the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote that you have a function definition in file that you include. I suspect that the reason is the function redeclaration error.

You should move the function definition from `myCustomFile.php` to `functions.php`.

You can also before each function definition in `myCustomFile.php` check whether there is already a function of the same name.

```
if ( ! function_exists('you_function_name') ) {
    function you_function_name() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: moving the functions into the `functions.php` file worked. thank you.